# Colors shown differently in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a input text box of `#c7e296` color and when in focus then color changes to `#668933` but when I test this in different browser they show some different colors on focus.

Can someone explain why?

Below is my code,

```
.after input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid   #668933; 
}

.before input[type="text"] {
    border: 2px solid #c7e296;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: What browsers? Can you post pictures of the differences you're seeing?

Comment: read this: http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers (notably Safari) do a highlight around a focussed input field themselves. So if you set a border, *and* the browser does its highlight, the colors can bleed together.

You can disable that by putting `outline-width: 0` on your `:focus` rule(s):

```
.after input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid   #668933; 
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: that was a nice solution.. can you please tell why this happens that outline width makes it display different colors

Comment: @ankurjain: By setting the width of the outline the browser adds to `0`, we *hide* it entirely.